# Test for non-numeric variables

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

I have a table, testdata, with numeric and non-numeric data.

```
testData = {{1, 2, 3, no, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9.1}, {1, y, y, n, n}};
```

I can locate the positions of numeric data easily

```
goodloc = Position[testData, _?NumericQ]

(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2,   5}, {3, 1}} *)
```

I would like an equally simple means to locate non-numeric variables

I have been able to get this result by using this code

```
 allPos = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 5}], 1];
 badloc = Complement[allPos, goodloc]

(* {{1, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}} *)
```

Is there a single expression that will do this?

Comment: your oneliner might look like `Complement[Flatten[MapIndexed[#2 &, testData, {2}], 1], 
 Position[testData, _?NumericQ]]`

Answer (score 16):

You can simply do:

```
Position[testData, _?(Not@*NumericQ), {2}, Heads -> False]
```

> `{{1, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}}`

Notice the use of level specification so that you only look inside the sublists and the option `Head -> False` prevents you from including the position of `Head`s, since they are non-numeric.
An alternative is to use `Except` as Kglr mentioned in the comments:

```
Position[testData, Except[_?NumericQ], {2}, Heads -> False]
```

Comment: ... or `Position[testData, Except[_?NumericQ], {2}, Heads -> False]` (+1)

Comment: @kglr. Thanks, that's a good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

```
Position[Map[NumericQ, testData, {-1}], False]
```

> `{{1, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}}`

Comment: or `Position[Map[NumericQ, testData, {2}], False]`

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you